# Game theory payoff table - small correction needed

Tags: tables, tabulary

I would like to create a payoff matrix that looks like this:

[image]

With the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Suspect 2} \\\cline{3-4}
& {} &{Quiet}  &{Fink}  \\\cline{2-4} 
&{Quiet} & {4,4} & {0,6}  \\ \cline{2-4}
Suspect 1  &{Fink} & {6,0} & {2,2}  \\\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}
```

I've got it looking like this:

[image]

Help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand\ml[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{#1}}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{lc|c|c|}
\mcc{}          &   \mcc{Suspect 2}         \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &           &   Quiet   &   Fink        \\
    \cline{2-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Suspect 1}
    &   \ml{Quiet}  &   4,4     &   0,6     \\
    \cline{2-4}
    &   \ml{Fink}   &   6,0     &   2,2     \\
    \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

*edit:* as suggested [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex) in her comment below, table is now stretched by factor 1.3.

Comment: Already awake? You were faster that me! I was just posting the same answer, the only difference is I would add `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}` :)

Comment: Works like a charm - learned  a few new tricks in the process!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, still awake ... :-(, so i'm bit tiered and forgot to suggest table more "open" ...

Comment: Still awake?! You should go to sleep, then! Good night :):):)